# Campagnolo 11 speed chainrings on a 10 speed crank

Tags: crankset, campagnolo, compact-crankset

## Context:

I currently run a full Campagnolo Athena (2015) groupset on one of my bicycles, including a Campagnolo Athena PowerTorque compact chainset (50-34, 110BCD).

The crank arms I specified on my bike are 175mm, however recently I have started to prefer shorter cranks. I have 165mm cranks on my other bike, however given the lowest available Campagnolo crank length (to my knowledge), of 170mm, I have been seeking 170mm cranks.

Given the age of the groupset, this has been challenging to say the least; precisely zero Athena 170mm compact cranks have come up on the used market that I've been able to find (albeit some standard 53/39 ones have, but these don't suit my riding preferences/style).

However, a set of Veloce (10 speed) 170mm cranks with 110BCD and compact chainrings have come on the market. This leads me to my question:

## Question

**Is it possible to fit chainrings designed for an 11 speed Campagnolo groupset to a crankarm/spider designed for 10 speed, and for it to work properly?**

My intention would be to transfer the (still decent condition) chainrings from my existing 11 speed Athena chainset over to the spider of the 10 speed 170mm Veloce chainset, however I'd like to make sure that this would work before committing to the work and potentially damaging or prematurely wearing out components.

The crankarm design between these generations of groupset appear to me to be identical; same BCD and same 5 bolt design with the one extended length bolt behind the crank arm, so I believe it should work unless there is a tolerance that I am missing (e.g. pitch/width of the spider mount itself or similar).

*PS: As an unrelated aside, in case anyone thinks to comment on the possibility; the Veloce 10 speed cranks in question happen to be UltraTorque not PowerTorque but this is easily worked-around by replacing the BB cups with appropriate UT cups which are thankfully still readily available, and I already have the appropriate tools for installation/bearing replacement if necessary etc.*

Comment: Related but in opposite direction: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/45718/can-i-run-campagnolo-10-speed-chainrings-on-11-speed-crank-arms?rq=1. It looks like the answer is no, but why not use crankset from different manufacturer?

Comment: @ojs I read the responses to that question but I don't think there seemed to be any actual consensus in answer. The direction of change seems highly relevant also to me which is why I asked a separate question. As for using a different manufacturer's crankset - aesthetics! If you can suggest an aesthetically matching 170mm (or 165mm) compact chainset then I'm all ears! (Albeit that's a workaround, not a solution; the question remains valid in any case).

Comment: Adding to the above, I'd actually say that the response mentioning dishing of the machining of the rings is what lead me to ask my question, since the dishing is on the removable part. I could equally have just asked "are the spiders the same on these groupset components" I suppose; Campy make it hard to find this stuff out on your own IME unlike e.g. Shimano.

Comment: Yes, the dishing is the relevant part and the person who wrote that works for Campagnolo service center so he should know. Basically, 10 and 11 speed rings have different dimensions so they aren't cross compatible in either direction.

Comment: Respectfully, we appear to be coming to different conclusions based on the available information. Worst comes to the worst, I can measure the components myself and answer the question for any future visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some early version 11s chainrings on a 10s crankset but not later.
All Athena 11s chainrings are generally suitable because they never changed their fitting system - a male / female two part bolt system was used and the bolts were shouldered to fit a standard chainring bolt hole.

Early SR, RE and CH rings, up until model year 2012, the same.

After MY2012 the higher range rings changed fitting systems, using a female thread in the inner chainring and consequently, the drillings in the spider that take the chainring bolts changed size - so compatibility was lost.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I ended up purchasing the used 10 speed Veloce chainset and as you say, the rings fit the spider as the spider is nearly identical. The only point of note that I can find is that the mounting point on the spider is ~0.5mm thicker on the 10 speed spider meaning that chainrings will be slightly further apart, however from various resources I've found, backwards compatibility typically isn't an issue here (forward compatibility is however).